# list of travelled countries in DS-160, US visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I am an Indian citizen currently in Australia on a student visa. I am applying for a B1 visa (US). Should I write "India" in the countries travelled or "Australia"? I certainly have been to India in the last 5 years and currently, I am in Australia.

Thanks for any help.
Pawan

Comment: I don't think you can go wrong listing both.

Answer (score 3):

**List both** countries (in addition to any other country you may have travelled to). You have travelled to India, and you have travelled to Australia (when you returned from India).

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are travelling on an Indian passport and are currently living in Australia you should list both countries. It doesn't hurt to add extra information to your application.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, if you're in doubt about how to answer a question, give the answer that conveys more information.  Maybe they don't care that you mention Australia, since you're obviously there now, but they're not going to object if you include it.

On the other hand, maybe they *do* want you to mention Australia.  You certainly don't want to omit Australia if they think you should include it, because they might refuse your visa application in that case.

I suppose they don't care whether you mention Australia, and I also suppose that they do want you to mention India, but using the logic described above, I would advise you to include both.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense.